# Ruby's `delete_if` method

Tags: ruby

This code:

```
string="abacdb"
string=string.split("")
string.delete_if{|x| x==string[0]}
puts(string)
```

returns `["b","a","c","d"]` instead of `["b","c","d","b"]`. Why doesn't this delete if `x=="a"`? Can anyone tell me why this method doesn't work as I hope?

Comment: This code should actually result in `string` being an empty array. You're deleting the first element of the array for each item in the array. Since the next item becomes the first element after the previous one gets deleted, the block always returns true, thus resulting in an empty array.

Comment: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if

Comment: Once the "a" is deleted and the "b" becomes string[0], the iterator will move to position 2 to compare the new string[1] with string[0], which is "a" == "b".  The next possible character that will match string[0] is the final "b".

Comment: To avoid this problem, you should use [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-reject), which doesn’t change the original string: `new_string = string.reject { |char| char == string[0] }`. If you still wanted to use [`delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-delete_if), which always modifies the original string, you could write `first_char = string[0]`, and then put `{|x| x == first_char}` in the `delete_if` block.

Comment: Your code prints `"b\na\nc\nd"` and returns `nil`. It does not return `["b","a","c","d"]`.

Comment: After your first statement, the variable `string` holds an `array`. You should avoid such confusing naming. Similarly, don't use variables `array` for a hash or `hash` for a string.

Answer (score 3):

`delete_if` iterates by incrementing the index for `x`, and deletes an element immediately after evaluating the block with respect to the element. It proceeds like the following.

- index of `x`: `0`

  ```
  string                      # => ["a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  string[0]                   # => "a"
  x                           # => "a"
  delete_if{|x| x==string[0]} # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  ```
- index of `x`: `1`

  ```
  string                      # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  string[0]                   # => "b"
  x                           # => "a"
  delete_if{|x| x==string[0]} # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  ```
- index of `x`: `2`

  ```
  string                      # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  string[0]                   # => "b"
  x                           # => "c"
  delete_if{|x| x==string[0]} # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  ```
- index of `x`: `3`

  ```
  string                      # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  string[0]                   # => "b"
  x                           # => "d"
  delete_if{|x| x==string[0]} # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  ```
- index of `x`: `4`

  ```
  string                      # => ["b", "a", "c", "d", "b"]
  string[0]                   # => "b"
  x                           # => "b"
  delete_if{|x| x==string[0]} # => ["b", "a", "c", "d"]
  ```